# How to save a generated parse tree as a .svg file for ANTLR4 plugin on IntelliJ?

Tags: svg, intellij-idea, antlr4, grammar

I've tried looking online for help, but I can't seem to figure out how to save a Parse Tree from the preview as a .svg file. The only options I get are "Export to image (white background)" or "Export to image (transparent background)". This saves the Parse Tree as a .png file which is not what I want.

The ANTLR4 plugin git page says that you should be able to save the parse tree as a .svg file by right clicking on the background of the Parse Tree preview.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that is a bit misleading. The default is `.png`, but if you change the extension to `.svg` and then save it, an SVG file is created.